como mejorar la seguridad en mi sitio
De que manera puedo mejorar la seguridad para la conexión a la base de datos, es decir que mi sitio sea lo mas seguro posible, a nivel código.
Tengo un archivo global.php con los datos del host y el archivo de conexión, así como algunos filtros para evitar la inserción de código y otras cosas.
Con jQuery valido el formulario a nivel front-end y con PHP también hago una validación a nivel back-end.
Mi duda es como realizar la conexión a la base o como realizar mas filtros para las consultas.
Archivo global.php:
**   define("DB_HOST","localhost");
     define("DB_NAME", "miproyecto");
     define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
     define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
     define("DB_ENCODE","utf8");
     define("PRO_NOMBRE","st");**

Archivo conexion.php:
    require_once "global.php";
    $conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    mysqli_query( $conexion, 'SET NAMES "'.DB_ENCODE.'"');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    printf("Falló conexión a la base de datos: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
   }
    if (!function_exists('ejecutarConsulta'))
    {
    function ejecutarConsulta($sql)
    {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
    function ejecutarConsultaSimpleFila($sql)
    {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);        
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        return $row;
    }
    function ejecutarConsulta_retornarID($sql)
    {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);        
        return $conexion->insert_id;            
    }
    function limpiarCadena($str)
    {
        global $conexion;
        $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,trim($str));
        return htmlspecialchars($str);
    }
   }


Hola. El código mostrado arroja poca información para saber si hay problemas de seguridad. De entrada, esto puede serlo: printf("Falló conexión a la base de datos: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());. No conviene nunca mostrar en pantalla mensajes internos, los cuales podrían arrojar información relativa a las credenciales de conexión. Luego, si lo que ejecutas con query son instrucciones con datos proporcionados por el usuario, ahí tienes un gravísimo riesgo de inyección SQL. Pero no se ve el contexto donde se generan esas consultas, así que no se puede hablar con más propiedad.
